# curl -X POST -F to java with Apache Commons / Android HTTP library

Tags: java, android, curl

can someone help me out with uploading a file via HTTP POST using the Apache Commons library. The equivalent call with curl is

curl -X POST -F  dataname=@filename https_url

What I have tried is

---

```
HTTPClient c = new DefaultHTTPClient();
HttpPost p = new HttpPost(https_url);
// initialize header fields as required
p.setHeader("key","value"); 
// ...

// Attempt 1, did not work
p.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(dataArray)); 

// Attempt 2, did not work
Parts[] parts = new Part[1];
File f = File.createTempFile("filname","extension");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.write(dataArray);
parts[0] = new FilePart("dataname", f);
MultiPartEntity e = new MultiPartEntity(parts);
p.setEntity(e);  // also did not work

HttpResponse response. client.execute(p, new BasicHttpContext());
```

---

Response is always 400, Bad Request

Is this not working with https ?
Do I need to manually add data to the file to make everything work ?
Di I need to set a content type ?

Comment: In C# I would be able to use AddFiles, and everything works...

Comment: I recommend you use okhttp instead Apache http. I may provide example for it, if you want